# Flutter: stuck getting collection from Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

```
DocumentReference ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('invoices')
        .doc(authService.getUser().uid); // or non existing ID

    // here works if I return {}

    final doc = await ref.get();
    final data = doc.data();
```

When trying locally either with simulator or with real device (connected by usb) works fine, but in released app, the await takes for ever.

This was also working ok before updating to flutter 2.8 but now it fails only on Android

Comment: Do you handle possible exceptions?

Comment: Your document is literally named "authService.getUser().uid", that exact string?

Comment: @DougStevenson good catch, I was testing with wrong ids to check what I got instead, but not related to the error anyway

Comment: @Riwen I handle possible null Map savedCompanyInfo = data != null ? data as Map<String, dynamic> : {}; but what's the exception for that? It always return something, right?

Comment: `get` always returns an instance of `Future`, yes. However, futures may complete with an error, which you should *really* handle, in my opinion.

Comment: @Riwen you were right. I put everything inside a trycatch and returned {} in case something was wrong. But I don't know why only in released app this error is happening (and know sure how to check what the error ir)

Comment: Had to open a different question for that since this was resolved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70406740/flutter-not-getting-collection-in-released-app

Comment: Should I repost my comment as an answer so that you can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting my comments as they seemed to have helped:

You should handle possible exceptions. The `get` method returns an instance of `Future`, which may complete with an error. When awaiting it, it may throw.

Comment: specific code in my answer

Answer (score 1):

I put everything inside a trycatch

try {
DocumentReference ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('invoices')
.doc(authService.getUser().uid);

```
      final doc = await ref.get();
      final data = doc.data();

      Map savedCompanyInfo = data != null ? data as Map<String, dynamic> : {};
      myRents.companyInfo = savedCompanyInfo;

      return savedCompanyInfo;
    } catch (e) {
      return {};
    }
```